# How to split a string after every ]

Tags: php

I have a string in an array like format.

```
["1","Data","time"] ["2","Data","time"] ["3","Data","time"] ["4","Data","time"]
```

I am trying to split the code after every ] - The data inside the [] could vary everytime so i cant use str_split();

I want to keep all the brackets in tack so they dont cut off so i cant use explode

Thank You

Comment: have you tried preg_match_all() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: may you can split with explode()

Comment: It's almost json, check my edit.

Comment: If there is a space between each ] [ pair and no other spaces (like in your example) you might try exploding on a space.

Answer (score 2):

Easy regex:

```
$s = '["1","Data","time"] ["2","Data","time"] ["3","Data","time"] ["4","Data","time"]';
preg_match_all('/\[[^\]]+\]/', $s, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

But actually it's almost json, so:

```
$s = '["1","Data","time"] ["2","Data","time"] ["3","Data","time"] ["4","Data","time"]';
$s = '[' . str_replace('] [', '],[', $s) . ']';
print_r(json_decode($s));
```

Maybe you have a fragment or modified json, so it may be easier if you have actual json.

Comment: Some sort of retaliatory down vote or is there some constructive criticism?

Comment: +1 cause this is what I thought he was asking for. I ran your code and it indeed delivers exactly what he specified so who knows why it was downvoted. Maybe the json comment? I don't know

Comment: Well, its almost json, maybe they got the string from somewhere and have manipulated it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '["1","Data","time"] ["2","Data","time"] ["3","Data","time"] ["4","Data","time"]';
$newStr = trim($str,'[');
$newStr1 = trim($newStr,']');
$arr = explode('] [',$newStr1);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: "*I want to keep all the brackets in tack so they dont cut off so i cant use explode*"

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution (if you don't want regular expression) would be using trim 1 char from both sides and then explode by ']['.

Example:

```
$string = "[123][456][789]";
$string = substr($string,1,strlen($string)-1);

$array = explode('][',$string);
```

Comment: how you can remove first [ and last ]?

Comment: @JA: What if the first and/or last characters are different?

Comment: Looking at the pattern, they probably won't. And even if they are, the delimiter would likely to change as well which means regex (even) won't cut it. and also, it says the easiest solution (without regex).